# Error 504 when downloading apps from Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store, installation, system-error

My device is [Motorola Xoom MZ604](http://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_xoom_mz604-3833.php). The internet connectivity is [4G WiMax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiMAX) via my laptop as hotspot. 
The problem is when I'm trying to download any app from Google Play Store, it gives me an **Error 504** with the message I mentioned in title.

However, if I navigate to the application via browser and click: `Install → Select Device → Install` and then restart my device, it sometimes works.

Some googling brought me that it's a gateway timeout error. But I'm still unable to figure out how to work around the problem. So looking forward for your help.

Comment: A screenshot showing the full message would help, as error 504 can mean different things.

Answer (score 10):

According to the [list of status codes at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error), a 504 error means the following:

> **504 Gateway Timeout**
>   The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and did not receive a timely response from the upstream server.

In other words: the culprit should neither be (on) your device, nor (at) Google Play -- but in between.

A [thread on the Nook forum](http://www.androidfornook.com/forum/thread-897.html) describes the very same problem, and one of the conclusions there is:

> Generally, that means a Gateway error and I would suspect the problem being on the router end rather than the Nook side. Sometimes a router reset will cure it.

Which corresponds to my conclusion. So if you're using mobile data, it *might* help to switch data off and on again (or better: switch to *airplane mode* and back), in the hope you will get a connection into a different segment of your provider's network (and thus a different gateway on that end).

---

From a thread on XDA about all the [Google Play Error Codes](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2733038)

> **Method 1:**
>
> - clear data
> - clear cache of google play store & google service framework
>
> **Method 2:**
>
> - remove your gmail account
> - reboot
> - Re-add account

---

Funnily, the very same issue comes to a very different conclusion [on Yahoo answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120801083227AAAP1ji): here the user had not enough space on his device, so after removing some other app it suddenly worked. I suspect this was a co-incidence (when he tried again after having freed up space, the gateway was "fixed") -- but it cannot hurt to check for that.

---

Several more sulutions might pop up with the time. To me it proved helpful to [search Google for '"Google Play" "error 504"'](http://www.google.de/search?q="google+play"+"error+504").

Comment: I added some info I found on XDA about the error code. Didn't want to create a new answer because this one has a lot of useful information about what it could be, and solutions.

Comment: Thanx, @RyanConrad – but I doubt that clearing *local* data can solve anything on the *remove server*: 5xx are *server-side* errors. So what should manupulating the local installation achieve here? Except, of course, if the connection "playstore error code <-> HTTP response code" is totally wrong.

Comment: I don't know if 504 error from google play is the same as a 504 HTTP error. If it actually is an HTTP 504, i agree, it won't fix anything on the server.

Comment: Yeah. Unfortunately, that XDA post doesn't speak about *reasons*, just about *possible solutions*.

Comment: found some more info that says a [504 error is INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED](http://www.titaniumtrack.com/kb/titanium-backup-kb/titanium-backup-troubleshooting.html#error504) - this is comments to a bug fixed in titanium backup, but it's more info :)

Comment: Thanks again, @RyanConrad! And more confusion: What UID changed? That of the (installed) app? In that case, the XDA solution wouldn't help. Here are [several pointers at SO on `INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED+answers%3A1) suggesting completely different approaches. If that's the same error, that is: some of those questions rather connect it to the "-24" error.

Comment: [UID](http://www.linfo.org/uid.html) is usually consider the UserID, sometimes called a SID in windows. Which if it did "change", then it would make sense as to why those methods do work, because it re-initializes the UID (method 2), or re-caches what it thinks the UID is (method 1).

Comment: -504 being INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED as opposed to HTTP 504 seems likely given that installing a Chrome update on the M developer preview fails with -504 (because the package is not built for M IIRC)

Answer (score 3):

Hope this will help someone.

In my case I was trying to upgrade the app (currently installed on device) which has Target SDK 23 to the app (newly uploaded app in play store) which has target sdk 22.

Comment: Yes the log said : "Error -504 while installing <package>: -26: Package <package> new target SDK 21 doesn't support runtime permissions but the old target SDK 23 does"

Comment: I'm not sure this is a comprehensive solution to OP's question.  For example, I uninstalled all previous instances of the app from my phone, tried to reinstall it through Google Play, and still getting this error.

Comment: @IgorG. unfortunately you need to uninstall the app from all the device which uses this a/c... (for ex. if three devices using same account and u have installed app using this a/c, you need to uninstall the app from all three  devices to get rid of the error.)

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting the play store app. You won't lose your apps following these steps. Nothing important will be lost.

Steps to follow on a motorola xoom

1. Go to the app drawer (menu)
2. Tap settings
3. Tap applications
4. Tap the "All" tab
5. Scroll through and look for play store
6. Tap Play Store (not play store services!)
7. Tap "clear data"
8. You will then get a warning, click "ok"

That's it, go through your problem again and see if it fixed. Bear in mind you will have to re-accept the terms and conditions for the play store app, when this comes up, simply click "accept"

Comment: Great i will try this out and let you know.

Comment: Ok. Glad I could help!

Comment: Ya :) i will surely reply about how your solution worked for me but probably will be a bit late. being busy at this moment :(

Answer (score 1):

This could also appears when you trying to install an app that is not install on the current user, but still installed on the guest or another user.

You have more that one user on Lollipop devices.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the phone into Airplane mode and back did the trick for me. So it most likely was indeed the Gateway issue. Tip though. Dont just turn it on then off. Wait about 60 seconds before you turn airplane mode off again. If you just toggle it, it picks up the same gateway.