# Google Play Error code “-504”

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-services

I'm facing an annoying issue with Google Play over and over again. There are some apps (currently Deezer and Teamtreehouse) which can't be updated/installed due this error:

**"Can't install App" (Error code: -504)**

FYI: This is not a 504 but negative 504 error

The only working solution what I found is the factory reset an wiping the whole phone, which is really annoying doing this every month. My question is, someone has easier solution for this error?

I have tried all solution what I found:

- force stopping play store / play store framework
- clearing data
- clearing cache of google play store & google service framework
- removing  gmail account
- side-loading apps
- directly installing apks
- searching apps related files on phone and removing them

Image of the error:

[image]

My phone details:
Xperia M4 Aqua

Android 5.0

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! You've already correctly tagged your question `google-play-store`. Most of our tags have helpful wikis attached, [so has this](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-play-store/info). We've collected posts to known errors there, so please check: [Error 504 when downloading apps from Play Store?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35062/16575) Good luck!